# iPad: file was built for armv7 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have been developing my app using Simulator and an old iPhone 4S.

I tried to run the app on an iPad Mini 3, but I get this warning:

```
file was built for armv7 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)
```

any idea on how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

The error was related to the UnitTest target.
I deleted such target (as I am not doing unit tests) and the warning disappeared.

Comment: Validate the current architecture like we have `i386` for `iOS Simulator or 32 bit build on mac os` and `armv6 armv7 arm7s` for ios device and `x86_64` for mac os x

Answer (score -1):

For each target that needs to be built:

Go to Build Settings > Architectures

- Set to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`

Go to Build Settings > Valid Architectures

- Set to `arm64`, `armv7`, `armv7s`

Perform a **Product > Clean** just to be safe and **Product > Build** your project for the iPad Mini 3.

Comment: I made a screenshot of the Archtitectures, it seems settings are ok. I even performed a Clean, but the warning didn't leave.

Comment: Here's something to try: delete your DerivedData files: Preferences > Locations > click the tiny arrow next to DerivedData. Then try rebuilding.

Comment: @daniel Thanks! That did it for me. I was having this issue after the latest upgrade to Xcode 8.3 (and Swift 3.1)

Comment: @PeterKovacs, thanks for your feedback. It's nice to learn that those procedures still apply to the latest Xcode projects.