# Xcode Swift file was built for arm64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

Tags: xcode, swift, ipad, armv7, arm64

When I run my project on my iphone or in the simulator it works fine.

When I try to run it on an ipad I get the below error:

*file was built for arm64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)*

The devices it set to Universal.
Does anybody have an idea about what else I should check?

Comment: please follow the following stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691582/ipad-file-was-built-for-armv7-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked-arm64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have added armv6 for iPad 2. Done that and it works now

Answer (score 8):

Just in case somebody has the same problem as me. Some of my target projects had different iOS Deployment target and that is why the linking failed. After moving them all to the same the problem was solved.

Comment: You're right. I think it's because iOS 11 dropped all 32-bit support (so all armv6 and 7s). If the deployment target of a framework dependency is 11, it won't build those architectures, but if the deployment target of the app itself is e.g. <11, it will still need them to create a fat binary. Either set all deployment targets to 11 to get a single arm64 build, or set them all to <11 to get a fat binary of arm64, armv7 and armv7s.